# Button on Document List Item to open "Properties Pane"

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a document list in Microsoft Sharepoint Online.
While there are several ways to open the properties pane using the UI, I would like to have a button on each item in the document list that will open the properties pane on that item. (Essentially selecting that item then open the properties pane).

I have tried the following to create a link on each item...

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "a",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"attributes": {
"target": "_blank",
"href": "='https://apps.powerapps.com/play/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?tenantId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&ID='+[$ID] + '&hidenavbar=true'"
}
}
```

where the first set of x's is the App-ID and the second set is the powerapp tenant ID.

I know the target shouldn't be there and that the href will open a new page.  But I don't know what to use there instead, if this is even possible.

I currently just get a blue page with a spinner.  It suggests an invalid tenant or app ID, but even if I got that to work, I doubt it would produce the behaviour as what the UI produces, which is just having the side panel slide out.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a button that opens the properties panel.

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "Publish",
"customRowAction":{
   "action" : "editProps" 
}
}
```